# class object list not keeping memory appended objects - python

Tags: python, class, oop, data-structures

I am new to python and just started learning about object oriented.
I have a list of emails objects with class variable default `is_spam = False`

What I want to do is once a user marks email "i" as mark as spam, append that email to spam email(`spam_inbox`) list.

The problem is it seems every time I run the program, the `spam_inbox` resets to an empty list and return just latest element recently appended.

I was curious to know what I am doing incorrect; below is my code:

```
class Email():
    has_been_read = False
    is_spam = False

    def __init__(self,email_contents,from_address, ):
        self.email_contents= email_contents
        self.from_address = from_address

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.email_contents} from {self.from_address}"
    
    def mark_as_read(self):
        self.has_been_read = True
    
    def mark_as_spam(self):
        self.is_spam = True

mailbox = ["example@gmail.com, testing class variable in python",
        "exampleagain@yahoo.com, testing variable in python"]
user_choice =""

#while loop user to choose an option
while user_choice != "quit":
    user_choice = input("What would you like to do - read/mark spam/send/quit? ")
    if user_choice == "mark spam":
        get_spam_emails()

#get spam email is defined as 
spam_inbox = []
def get_spam_emails():
    user_choose = int(input("\nWhich email would you like to mark spam? Enter index number(eg: 0 for the first email): ")) 
    user_marked_spam = inbox[user_choose].mark_as_spam()
    print(user_marked_spam)
    spam_inbox.append(user_marked_spam)
    print("=======")
    return spam_inbox
```

I expected to have a spam list which increases in size every time a user select an email to mark as spam.
`get_spam_emails()` to return a list like below in case both emails were marked as spam:

```
spam_inbox = ["example@gmail.com, testing class variable in python",
        "exampleagain@yahoo.com, testing variable in python"]
```

Maany thanks

Comment: `spam_inbox = []` needs to be before `while user_choice != "quit":`

Comment: `spam_inbox` is not the same `spam_inbox` inside of `get_spam_emails()`

Comment: `mark_as_spam()` doesn't return anything. What are you expecting `user_marked_spam` to contain?

Comment: @drum Why not? They never assign the variable, so it's not a local variable.

Comment: Is `inbox` supposed to be `mailbox`? It contains strings, not `Email` instances, so you can't call `mark_as_spam()` on them.

Comment: mailbox contains a list of strings, once Email class is applied I append to inbox to create email objects.

Comment: user_marked_spam is supposed to change object which was is_spam = False to is_spam = True

Comment: `mark_as_spam()` is the class method to turn a marked spam email to True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete edit of my answer for a more complete OO approach based on `eli_257`'s comments.  I have added classes for the MailServer and MailBox.  You can add to these, or extend them, for other methods you will almost surely need, full CRUD for each object type.

Save it as a .py file and run it.  Each time through it should pick random emails to set as spam...

All objects have methods to accomplish their tasks.  For example, `class MailBox` has the method to move an email from the Inbox the SpamBox.

```
import uuid
import random
import copy


class Email:
    """A class that represents an email.
    
    """
    
    def __init__(self, email_contents, from_address, ):
        self.email_contents = email_contents
        self.from_address = from_address
        self.is_spam = False
        self.has_been_read = False
        self.email_id = uuid.uuid4()

    def to_str(self):
        return f"{self.email_contents} from {self.from_address}"

    def mark_as_read(self):
        self.has_been_read = True


class MailBox:
    """A class to represent all email boxes for a user
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):  # use Key Word Args to capture init properties
        self.username = kwargs['username'] if 'username' in kwargs else ''
        if 'email_address' not in kwargs:
            print("Email Address is a required parameter for creating MailBox!")
        else:
            self.email_address = kwargs['email_address']
        self.inbox = {}
        self.spam_box = {}

    def add_to_inbox(self, email_to_add):
        """

        :type email_to_add: Email
        """
        email_id = email_to_add.email_id
        self.inbox[email_id] = email_to_add

    def move_to_spam(self, email_to_move):
        email_id = email_to_move.email_id
        self.spam_box[email_id] = email_to_move
        del self.inbox[email_id]

    def mark_spam_emails(self, spam_email):
        # Simulate user input
        username = self.username
        spam_email.is_spam = True
        self.move_to_spam(spam_email)
        email_from = spam_email.from_address
        print(f"Email from '{email_from}' added to SpamBox for user '{username}"'')


class MailServer:
    """A class to hold MailBox objects

    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.mailboxes = {}
        if 'username' in kwargs:
            self.username = kwargs['username']
            self.mailbox = kwargs['mailbox']
            self.add_mailbox(username=self.username, mailbox=self.mailbox)

    def add_mailbox(self, username, mailbox):
        self.mailboxes[username] = mailbox


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Everything below the line above only runs if you are running this .py 
    # file as a script.  It will not run if you import this .py as a module
    #
    # Everything that follows is code to test the objects/ methods.  
    # There is a probably quite a few more tests that would be needed.
    #
    # test data for users mail boxes, each with 2 emails.
    test_data = {
        'tom': {
            'email_address': 'tom@example.com',
            'emails': [
                {
                    'email_contents': "Hi, Top. Welcome to python.",
                    'from_address': "example1@gmail.com"
                },
                {
                    'email_contents': "Thanks for subscribing, Tom!",
                    'from_address': "example2@gmail.com"
                },
            ]
        },
        'bob': {
            'email_address': 'bob@example.com',
            'emails': [
                {
                    'email_contents': "Hi, Bob. Welcome to python.",
                    'from_address': "example3@gmail.com"
                },
                {
                    'email_contents': "Thanks for subscribing, Bob!",
                    'from_address': "example4@gmail.com"
                },
            ]
        }
    }

    # Create a MailServer to hold mailboxes...
    email_server = MailServer()
    # Create the Users and populate their mailboxes with emails
    for username in test_data:
        email_data = test_data[username]
        email_address = email_data['email_address']
        user_emails = email_data['emails']
        user_mailbox = MailBox(email_address=email_address,
                               username=username
                               )
        # Add this user and their inbox to the mail server        
        email_server.add_mailbox(email_address, user_mailbox)
        for user_email_data in user_emails:
            from_address = user_email_data['from_address']
            email_contents = user_email_data['email_contents']
            new_email = Email(email_contents=email_contents, from_address=from_address)
            user_mailbox.add_to_inbox(new_email)

    # Test Code to go through users mail boxes and mark email as spam
    for username in email_server.mailboxes:
        user_mailbox = email_server.mailboxes[username]
        user_inbox_ref = user_mailbox.inbox
        # Make a deepcopy of the inbox dictionary, as it will likely change size and 
        #  the iterator will not like that... 
        user_inbox = copy.deepcopy(user_inbox_ref)
        for email_id in user_inbox:
            # Random(ish) decision on whether email is spam
            is_spam = bool(random.getrandbits(1))
            email_to_set_as_spam = user_inbox[email_id]
            email_from_address = email_to_set_as_spam.from_address
            if is_spam:
                print(f"Moving email from '{email_from_address}' to Spam Box for user '{username}'.")
                user_mailbox.move_to_spam(email_to_set_as_spam)
            else:
                print(f"Email from '{email_from_address}' Not Spam for user '{username}'.")
```

Comment: The above code works.  I had issues with `code` formatting, so it a little terse.  Read the comments that explain a few things, addressing the comments on the OP.  `get_spam_emails` was called before its def.  `inbox` was not a valid variable and it needs to contain a list of Email objects.  Remove the 'simulate user input' parts and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help all and David; 
The above code works when first element is added. When run the second time but still returns the latest element added. In the function `get_spam_emails()` when I change to `user_choose = 1` for example, I still get the latest. What I was looking to have to have the appended list `spam_inbox = []` updated and increase in size as more objects are marked as spam. I am wondering if there is a way to achieve that. 
Many thanks again

Comment: I've edited my answer and added objects to support the operations you mentioned.

Comment: Big thank you; tested and works perfectly. I will build on this!

Comment: Thanks. Don't forget to Vote and/or Accept the answer if you like it.

Comment: Thanks; marked as answer and upvoted as well. Thanks for helping out beginner learners like me!!